# xargs command output is not predicated

Tags: shell, xargs

When I use `find` like this:

```shell
echo 1 2 3 | xargs  -I{} find {}
```

I get the following output:

```
find: ‘1 2 3’: No such file or directory
```

But when I use it like this:

```shell
echo 1 2 3 | xargs find
```

I get this output:

```
find: ‘1’: No such file or directory                             
find: ‘2’: No such file or directory          
find: ‘3’: No such file or directory
```

Why is the `{}` treated as a single string (i.e. only the newline is a separator) when using `-I{}`?

[image]

Comment: With `xargs  -I{}` the string value from `{}` (1 2 3) is passed a **single string/argument** whereas if you do not use `-I{}` the string will be passed as separate arguments. Try running `echo 1 2 3 | xargs  printf "%s\n"` and `echo 1 2 3 | xargs -I{} printf "%s\n" {}`

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and clarify what you are asking? Predicated on what? What you show is the normal, expected behavior, can you explain what you were expecting instead? If you tell us what you expect, we can explain why it didn't happen, but as it stands I don't know what part is confusing you here.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [documented feature](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) of `xargs -I`

```
 -I replace-str
              Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-
              arguments with names read from standard input.  Also,
              unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the
              separator is the newline character.  Implies -x and -L 1
```

Comment: Also,  unquoted blanks do not terminate input items;what's that mean?

Comment: It means you get the behaviour you are seeing -- items have to appear on separate lines to be considered as separate, whereas the default behaviour you observed considers spaces to be an item delimiter, unless they have been escaped (quoted).